# Update column based on value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
  HNCO_iloc    C_shift HNcoCA_iloc CA_shift i_FROM  i_TO
0        25  180.40469        None     None     36  None
0        70  179.52209        None     None     46  None
0       137  178.47112        None     None     49  None
0       157  178.35808        None     None     36  None
0       204  177.14190        None     None     32  None
0       221  176.99482        None     None     26  None
0       261  176.12322        None     None     16  None
0       269  176.08582        None     None     36  None
0       270  176.09042        None     None     36  None
0       313  175.27206        None     None     24  None
0       322  175.18865        None     None     31  None
0       332  174.78010        None     None     43  None
0       342  174.34505        None     None     45  None
0       352  173.76740        None     None      1  None
0       358  173.46177        None     None      3  None
0       363  172.97259        None     None      3  None
```

I want to be able to access the 'CA_shift' column using the values in 'i_FROM', and update that cell. So, for example, if I wanted to change the row that has i_FROM equal to 3, I would want the following output:

```
  HNCO_iloc    C_shift HNcoCA_iloc CA_shift i_FROM  i_TO
0        25  180.40469        None     None     36  None
0        70  179.52209        None     None     46  None
0       137  178.47112        None     None     49  None
0       157  178.35808        None     None     36  None
0       204  177.14190        None     None     32  None
0       221  176.99482        None     None     26  None
0       261  176.12322        None     None     16  None
0       269  176.08582        None     None     36  None
0       270  176.09042        None     None     36  None
0       313  175.27206        None     None     24  None
0       322  175.18865        None     None     31  None
0       332  174.78010        None     None     43  None
0       342  174.34505        None     None     45  None
0       352  173.76740        None     None      1  None
0       358  173.46177        None     test      3  None
0       363  172.97259        None     test      3  None
```

Right now I am doing:

```
connectivity_df.loc[connectivity_df['i_FROM' == 3], 'CA_shift'] = 'test'
```

But I am continually getting `KeyErrors`.

Comment: Try connectivity_df.loc[connectivity_df['i_FROM' ] == 3, 'CA_shift'] = 'test'

Comment: If you find it difficult to do this in pandas, it's probably not pandas.  Somewhere there's a problem w/your code, or you may have taken a non-optimal approach

Comment: I'm always the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with `np.where()`. The code would be as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CA_shift':[None,None,None,None,None,None],'i_FROM':[36,46,49,36,3,3]})
```

### 1st case: Replacing one to one:

```
example_value = 3
df['CA_shift'] = np.where(df['i_FROM'] == example_value,'test',df['CA_shift'])
```

Output:

```
  CA_shift  i_FROM
0     None      36
1     None      46
2     None      49
3     None      36
4     test       3
5     test       3
```

This operations works in a vectorized way like an `if` statement, where if the value for the row matches `example_value` it'll get updated to `test`, otherwise it'll return the original value for `CA_shift`.

### 2nd case: Replacing many to one:

```
mult_values = [3,46,49]
df['CA_shift'] = np.where(df['i_FROM'].isin(mult_values),'test',df['CA_shift'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  CA_shift  i_FROM
0     None      36
1     test      46
2     test      49
3     None      36
4     test       3
5     test       3
```

### 3rd case: Replacing many to many:

```
mult_values = [3,46,49]
conditions = [df['i_FROM']==mult_values[0],df['i_FROM']==mult_values[1],df['i_FROM']==mult_values[2]]
choices = ['test1','test2','test3']
df['CA_shift'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=df['CA_shift'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  CA_shift  i_FROM
0        0      36
1    test2      46
2    test3      49
3        0      36
4    test1       3
5    test1       3
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Python, pandas is super flexible and powerful, once you use it naturally you'll find it easy and awesome for your tasks!